# Reconstruir un archivo recibido como String - JAVA

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, base64

Quisiera saber si se puede "reconstruir" un archivo que se recibe como String.

Explico más a fondo mi caso, necesito descargar un pdf o zip, depende de lo que se escriba en la URL de petición, la cuestión es que no recibo directamente el archivo en la respuesta, sino que recibo un JSON con dos campos, uno es el nombre del archivo junto con la extensión y el otro campo es un String muy largo, si se pide el archivo en formato PDF llega a unos 21.000 caracteres, si es en ZIP, unos 2.000.

Se supone que debo generar el archivo desde ese String, pero todo lo que he encontrado por internet hasta ahora es escribir literalmente ese String en un fichero nuevo, pero eso no es lo que necesito.

¿Sabe alguien cómo poder hacer esto? Y más importante, ¿es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de 2 formas,1º en vez del JSON que te envían con la String del contenido, que te envíen directamente el fichero en base64, lo decodificas y mandas el fichero. 2º Creas un archivo con la strings que te llegan.

Comment: Yo creo que esos 21.000 caracteres es que el fichero está en Base64, así que es cuestión de descodificarlo y guardarlo en un fichero a parte

Comment: Si viaja en json es 100% seguro que es la cadena en Base64, si utilizas java 8 o superior puedes utilizar `byte[] archivoByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringRecibido);`  y luego para escribirlo en un archivo en pdf por ejemplo `OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.pdf");
out.write(archivoByte);`

Comment: Todos teníais razón con lo de Base64, no sabía que venía codificado de esa forma, lo he decodificado de manera similar a como lo indica @RobertoEMoran y escribiendo el array de bytes en un fichero ya es completamente legible. Muchísimas gracias a los 3!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola @JuanCarlosExpósitoRomero te dejo un ejemplo que realice para que entiendas como funciona la conversión, el ejemplo consiste en convertir un json de ejemplo y obtener el string de la imagen en Base64 que es lo que te debería de llegar en la respuesta y crear la imagen en el escritorio, solo debes cambiar la ruta a una en tu computadora y comprobar que el archivo fue creado correctamente, la imagen es del logo de github.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;

public class EjemploBase64AImagen {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Json de prueba con un campo imagen y el String de la imagen en Base64
       String json = "{\"imagen\":\"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\"}\n";

       // Clase para convertir el json a un map y poder obtener el valor de imagen.
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

       // convertimos el json, en caso sea a trabes de un framework como
       // Spring Boot el objeto de respuesta tendrá la propiedad de tipo String
       Map<String, String> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
       // obtenemos el valor del campo imagen
       String imagenBase64 = jsonMap.get("imagen");
        // El String Base64 lo decodificamos a un array de bytes
        byte[] archivoByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imagenBase64);
        // Escribimos el archivo de imagen en el escritorio, si es pdf solo cambia la extensión y el nombre según lo que necesites
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\java\\Desktop\\imagen.png");
        out.write(archivoByte);
        out.close();
    }
}
```