# Exportar a excel desde spring boot

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, postman

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Estoy desarrollando una API con Spring Boot, he realizado una consulta simple la cual estoy probando con Postman y todo funciona bien. pero necesito que ese resultado venga en un Excel.

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero es, enviar una petición vía post o get mediante postman y que se genere un Excel con tal resultado en una ruta especifica en mi proyecto o bien descargarlo automáticamente.

Si alguien me puede dar ideas o mostrar un ejemplo le agradecería mucho

Comment: Puedes  convertir el archivo un array de bytes y luego a Base64 para enviarlo como String en un campo de la respuesta junto a con algunos campos extras como el nombre y el tipo, hace poco conteste una pregunta que es recibiendo la respuesta json con una imagen en Base64 https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323594/reconstruir-un-archivo-recibido-como-string-java puede que eso te ayude a tener una mejor idea.

Comment: Lo que quieres realizar es posible utilizando las respuestas de mis compañeros, pero en buena practicas no creo que sea lo mejor, te explico, cualquier usuario con acceso al webservice podría descargar archivos segun los arrays de bytes, lo mejor que puedes hacer es enviar la solicitud de la petición al webservice, el te genera una URL temporal y con esa url obtienes el archivo.

Answer (score 1):

Mira te dejo un ejemplo sobre como descargar una imagen mediante un rest api el mismo principio aplica para el excel supongo que seran evidentes los cambios que tienes que hacer, en este caso mi endpoint primero se conecta a un sitio web y obtiene un image y la carga en memoria para despues ser servida al cliente final.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ImageResource {

    @GetMapping(path = "/download")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(String param) throws IOException {

        InputStream imageFromInternet = getImageFromInternet();
        int fileSize = imageFromInternet.available();
        InputStreamResource rs = new InputStreamResource(imageFromInternet);


        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"somefile.png\"")
                .contentLength(fileSize)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(rs);
    }


    private InputStream getImageFromInternet() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "gif", os);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
        return is;
    }
}
```

Uso

```
http://localhost:8080/api/download
```

Si tienes alguna duda comentalo en la caja de comentarios.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.. lo hice de esta manera:

Mi controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/excelexport")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> subVaribleExcel(@RequestBody SubVariable variable) throws IOException {
        List<SubVariableExcel> subVariableExcels = subVariableRepository.findAllForExcel(variable.getVariable_id());
        ByteArrayInputStream in = SubVariableExcelReport.subVariableExcel(subVariableExcels);
        // return IO ByteArray(in);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        // set filename in header
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=subVariables.xlsx");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new InputStreamResource(in));
    }
```

Mi services

```
public static ByteArrayInputStream generarExcel(List<Dato> datos) throws IOException {
        int columns = datos.size();//para generar total de columnas por ID encontrados
        try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datos");

            Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
            headerFont.setBold(true);
            headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());

            CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
            headerCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            headerCellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            // Header Row
            Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

            int col = 0;
            for (Dato dato : datos) {
                Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
                cell.setCellValue(dato.getNombre());
                cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
                col+=2;
            }

            Row headerRow2 = sheet.createRow(1);

            for (int colx = 0; colx < columns*2; colx++) {
                Cell cell = headerRow2.createCell(colx);
                if(colx%2==0)
                    cell.setCellValue("VALOR 1");
                else
                    cell.setCellValue("VALOR 2");

                sheet.autoSizeColumn(colx);
            }

            int firstCol = 0;
            int lastCol = 1;

            for (int colx = 0; colx < columns; colx++) {
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, firstCol, lastCol));
                firstCol+=2;
                lastCol+=2;
                //asi voy fucionando las columnas de 2 en 2 según numero de registro
            }
            workbook.write(out);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        }
    }
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Publico el código por si alguien mas lo necesita.

¿Alguien me podría decir como puedo mejorar el aspecto de mi Excel?
Quiero que las columnas de abajo tomen el mismo tamaño. He probado con autoSizeColumn pero solo se ajustan las primeras columnas como pueden ver en la imagen